# What is the best approach for handling multiple Service Accounts with Firebase Admin SDK?

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin

If I have multiple service accounts for different Firebase projects that I want to interact with, using the Firebase Admin SDK, what would the best approach be, considering that most actions will be triggered by events on a Primary Firebase Project?

There will be a Primary Firebase project that will trigger cloud functions on certain events that then have to go and perform actions on OTHER firebase projects.

The closest thing I found in Firebase's documentation is this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?authuser=0&hl=en#initialize-multiple-apps which I can definitely do, but now I need to know should I do that in a separate Node server or in the Primary Firebase projects Cloud Functions?

Here are the options I'm considering. I'm not sure if the first is even possible, can't find an answer when searching either, so any advice here would be appreciated:

1. Using Firebase cloud functions itself. This is probably not the right way, but I just want to ask and make sure. So my thinking here is if I have the Primary Firebase project that will do all the "management" of the other projects, is it possible to do actions on another Firebase project if I reference that Service Account key inside a function that's inside the cloud functions of the Primary project? Would I then do **another** admin.initializeApp() but with the other projects' service credentials **inside** of a function of the parent cloud functions? (I'm already hesitant about this solution, but maybe it's ok, idk?)
2. Using an Express app/Node Server: Would it be better to have a Node server independent of the primary Firebase project, that has endpoints that can perform the actions on the various other Firebase projects? The Functions triggered in the Primary Firebase cloud functions account will then call these endpoints. If this is the way, is it a safe approach to then use the primary Firebase account's Cloud Storage to store the different Service Account JSON files, then pass in the URL of the service account to that endpoint and initialize using that?

The shortened version of all this is, how do I, through cloud functions, perform actions on multiple Other Firebase projects? Thanks!

Comment: Rather than "update" your question with solution you took, consider self-answering the question instead leaving the question as it was.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I did go for the first option, it seems that you can actually use multiple apps in the Firebase admin SDK.

Here is a small example of how I would add a timestamp to the other Firebase project when I detect that a new service account has been added to my primary firebase project's `serviceAccounts` Firestore collection.

Note this is just an example, so there is an answer. I don't plan to actually implement this exact function. In this example the serviceAccount JSON file's data is stored as raw text in a Firestore Document, which I won't actually do.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Initialize Primary (Parent) Admin SDK
admin.initializeApp();

// User Service Account Upload
exports.newServiceAccount = functions.firestore
  .document("projects/{projectId}/service_accounts/{accountId}")
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const serviceAccount = snap.data();
    const projectId = context.params.projectId;

    // Initialize the app with a new service account if it does not already exist
    let userApp;
    if (admin.apps.includes(projectId)) {
      userApp = admin.app(projectId);
    } else {
      userApp = admin.initializeApp(
        { credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount) },
        projectId
      );
    }

    await userApp.firestore().collection("test").add({
      timestamp: new Date(),
    });
  });
```

There is a check in here to see if my other projects app has already been initialized.

This solution works for my use case, and I can now manage multiple Firebase projects with my one Primary Firebase project. (In Cloud Functions)